# How to proxy sudo

Tags: linux, sudo

Me and one other developer just inherited a web application from a team that has now been re-purposed to something else. Ironically, although we are responsible for maintaining and developing the app, the other team's systems people are still administrating and hosting the server out of their officec (about 1,000 miles away).

We just got access to a staging server and can log in with our AD credentials. However, in order to log into the QA and production servers, we must sudo in like so:

```
sudo -H -u fooUser -s
ssh qa.example.com
```

Where `fooUser` and `qa.example.com`, although dummy values for the sake of posting this question, are the superuser name and QA server alias, respectively.

My question is: **what is fooUser** and why must I sudo to it before SSHing to either the QA or prod servers?** I'm not a "Linux guy" so I'm just curious what kind of user magic voo doo is going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fooUser` is a user that has a `.ssh/` directory in their home directory that contains configuration and keys for the subsequent `ssh` command.

Comment: couldn't he just do an `ssh fooUser@qa.example.com` then?

Comment: Not 100% sure about this @Ignacio - when I log in to the staging server and run `pwd` I see `/export/login/myADUsername`

Comment: @jozzas: No, because that won't have the configuration or the keys.

Comment: @zharvey: The home directory on the *local* system.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Ah, there's a *local* account by that name with the required config. Is that a standard way for a sysadmin to set up SSH to a remote machine? I've never heard of this before.

Comment: @Ignacio - by *local* which do you mean, `staging.example.com` or `qa.example.com`? Remember I must first Putty (I'm on Windows 7) into `staging.example.com` and *then* SSH into `qa.example.com`.

Comment: The system you're running `ssh` on.

Comment: Not sure why this answer was voted down, it is almost certainly correct.  There is a private key in the fooUser ssh folder.  Given you have access to sudo to it, you could copy the private key to your own home directory .ssh folder and so skip the sudo.  If your admins were happy for you to do this.  Which they will not be.  Anyway, it is a bit of a silly way to manage the access.